# Fedora 38: Can't open an X11 display between two nearly identical systems; how do I track / fix this?

Tags: fedora, x11, display, fedora-38

From Red Hat 1.1 or so, I've stuck with Fedora, etc, out of familiarity, but for a LONG time - 20 years or more - I've been managing a site's servers from a Windows box and would run utilities like `gparted` from the comfort of my office. I ran `cygwin` on it and therefore an x server and it worked fine, plus the `cygwin` terminal is a LOT more friendly than any x-term I've yet found. ...The day finally came (yesterday) when I had to retire my old Windows 7 box, and, with my new Fedora 38 replacement, try as I might, I keep getting:

(gpartedbin:52444): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:20:10.330: cannot open display: 123.some.ip:0

I tried all the usual stuff, including:

```
$ xhost +

$ export DISPLAY=123.some.ip:0
```

And, since it's an internal net, even:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

just to be sure that wasn't it!

So far, no joy.

I DO note that my new "office user interface system" thinks its local display is just :0 so that's not really helpful. ... If it matters, it's Fedora 38, a unique hybrid of Server and Workstation but mostly all standard packages, just an odd mix of 'em.

Though it wasn't frequent, I KNOW I've done this sort of thing quite easily when I had to on older versions of Fedora, Debian, etc, and don't recall anything special to do.

Could it be the modern x-11 needs some kind of "pay attention to external connections!" kind of hint, similar to how Cygwin needs you to tell it to listen to TCP? If so, IDK how to do that.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After perhaps more than two day's time lost, I figured it out.

I don't have a fully comprehensive answer regarding when certain changes happened, but as of NOW, `Fedora 38`:

Somewhere along the way, `Fedora's Workstation Desktop`, which I installed over Server to get a somewhat familiar windowing system, switched from `Xorg` to something called `Wayland`.

`Wayland`, for whatever - in my view misguided - reason, think's using displays on another system is a security risk and disables the "remote display" capability by default, and they don't tell you how to turn it back on.

Exactly [how to turn it back on is now behind a paywall](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/43654) at Red Hat's web site, however, in reading the [various materials about Wayland,](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/system-administrators-guide/Wayland/) there's an open admission that "there are still applications and behaviors that don't work as expected," including, apparently, this important feature of `X11`.

My solution was:

During login, click the cog-wheel type logo and select running one of the two original `X-11` (AKA `Xorg`) options, and then continue as normal. You can still get caught up in firewall and `xhost` permissions - and maybe even `SELinux` - but above I indicated I'd taken those things out of the way.

Thus, once free of `Wayland`, "It Just Works!" ... Time to celebrate! And, HEY developers of `Wayland`, MAYBE you ought to TELL us stuff like this, perhaps HOW to overcome this one via commented out options in the config file?

Comment: The last time I looked at this in any depth, the remote display functionality wasn't working properly in Wayland and the implementation worked *very* differently from X. That may have changed. Meanwhile, when using X across the network, its advisable to tunnel it via ssh (supported out of the box).

Comment: @symcbean Do note that when "remote" is the next system over in the rack on the same internal subnet, your advice becomes, "it's advisable to tunnel via ssh and unnecessarily expend network bandwidth and CPU resources" ...Not in my book!

Comment: It's 2023. If 100KB/s vs 80KB/s is stressing your LAN something is very wrong. If the CPU overhead is more than 2%, something is very wrong.

Comment: @symcbean Spoken like a person who has never pushed anyhnig to the limit; you know where the limits are when you cross them! And, you're forgetting Ben Franklin's famous advice: "Watch your pennies and your pounds (dollars) will take care of themselves."

Comment: If you are surprised what is deemed an *insecure* default setting, you may be even more surprised by what was deemed *secure* defaults. Check your installed print/scan software, lest you get yourself some adversarial-controlled network traffic towards a network you believed to be sufficiently *"internal"* to not warrant mutual authenticated encrypted tunnels.

Comment: @anx ...If you've got any links, DO SHARE! And, not that I'll ever buy another one again, but if you (or anyone else) thinks the likes of HP are going to provide a way to have a "mutual authenticated encrypted tunnel", well, that'll get a laugh out of me! The damned thing wants to phone-home to HP every chance it gets and HP actually ripped us off of our TWO YEARS OF INK (said their advertisement) when we, appropriately, blocked the thing from internet access! (Are people _really_ stupid enough to... oh, nevermind! ;-)

Comment: Are you aware that not only there is RDP forwarding in GNOME on Wayland now, but also its performance does not suck these days, because Microsoft spent substantial work into making their client play nice with it, as part of their WSL efforts? Though enabling it on-the-fly might *not match your current workflow, to say it nicely* once you managed to do that your might find it to be much more responsive than working with directly with X.

Comment: @anx No, anx, I was not aware. ... Hey, if you know how to get Wayland to let the display connection work, DO SHARE!  ... I'm so busy with OTHER things that I readily admit I'm ignorant of a lot about - scratch that - MOST about Wayland. Before this, I didn't know why I should care!

Comment: @Richard_T if you are this concerned about optimization then don't use GUI tools; there are command line tools which will do the same job (and more) with much less overhead.